# Jump between the "if" and "fi" in vim, while editing a bash script?

Tags: vim

Just like you could jump between pairs, i.e `()`, can I extend this feature to jump between beginning tags and ending tags?

i.e in bash, jump between `if` and `fi`

Comment: On my system it does exactly that. I assume the `matchit` plugin is responsible for that. Usually it's installed by default with every larger vim installation. It is deactivated, though.

Comment: @Marco Hi, you're right, `%` does not work for shell scripts unless you have the `matchit` pluggin installed. Can you convert your comment to an answer and give the url to the `matchit` pluggin ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example. Suppose you have this code and you press `%`, the cursor jumps between { and } parens:

[image]

`matchit.vim` extends this functionality, you can do the same with `()` just move cursor on `(` and press `%`, it jumps between pairs of parenthesis ( )'s, { }'s, [ ]'s. It also jumps between opening and closing tags of C style comments /* and */. And it's smart enough to jump between C preprocessor directives - from #if to #endif and match #elif or #else in between

For more info refer to [catonmat.net](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-matchit-vim/) and [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39). Note that since vim 6.0, `matchit.vim` has been included in the standard vim distribution, under the `macros/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like match-up (from https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup), installed via [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).

from the README:

> #### Overview
>
> match-up can be used as a drop-in replacement for the classic plugin matchit.vim. match-up aims to enhance all of matchit's features, fix a number of its deficiencies and bugs, and add a few totally new features. It also replaces the standard plugin matchparen, allowing all of matchit's words to be highlighted along with the matchpairs ((){}[]).