# Matching opening and closing if statements in shell script (if...fi) using PHPStorm, vscode

Tags: scripting, osx, plugin, user-interface, ide

I hava bunch of these nested if..then...fi 's

```
if [ "${var}" = "NA" ]  
then  
    if [ "$var" != "SAM" -a "$fileFormat" != "XED" -a "$Format" != "TED" -a "$Format" != "ESTA" ]  
      then  
      echo "ERROR: Input file format not recognised"  
      echo "use --help for more information"  
      exit 1  
    fi  
    #convert esta to ted  -  start  
    if [ $fileFormat = "ESTA" ]  
    then  
        if [ $ENO != "NA" ]  
        then  
        ENO=$(greadlink -e ${ENO} )  
        fi  
        if [ -z "$output" ]  
        then  
        echo "WARNING"  
        echo "No output directory specified. Using current working directory, " $(pwd)/OUTPUT  
        output=$(pwd)/OUTPUT  
        fi  
    InputTed=$(greadlink -e ${Inputted}) #greadlink - to canonicanize/normalize to standard format  
    mkdir -p ${output}  
    cd ${output}  
    output=$(greadlink -e $(pwd) )  
    DIRECTORY=$(pwd)
```

In a more than 2000 line shell script. I would like to click on the opening if, and have the closing fi highlighted to easily navigate the code like it works with braces. I'm using PHPStorm, vscode but happy to try any free text editor that could do it out of the box or any plugin to these tools.

Comment: just to clarify the wording, those are *sequential* `if`s, not *nested* `if`s

Comment: Using indentation within your code would help tremendously.

Comment: Related, with an answer that applies to `vim` - [Jump between the `if` and `fi` in `vim`, while editing a `bash` script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60264/100397)

Comment: Further related, with instructions on making `matchit.vim` work - [Matchit not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7281459)

Comment: I have revised the question to give a better illustration of the scenario. Thanks for the tip on matchit, I have tried it but seems to only work on the braces. Note, am using mac os, high siera.

Answer (score 0):

#### Emacs

[Commands that work with balanced parentheses](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html) also understand balanced keywords in some languages, including sh. When the cursor is on an `if`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to go to the matching `fi`. From `fi`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to go to the matching `if`. (Mnemonic: **B**ackward/**F**orward; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is for simple things: characters; <kbd>Alt</kbd> is for moderately complex things: words; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> is for complex things: expressions.)

To highlight the parenthesis or keyword matching the one the cursor is on, turn on [Show Paren mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html). In the menu: ”Options“ → “Highlight Matching Parentheses”. To make this permanent:  ”Options“ → “Customize” → “Specific Option…” and enter `show-paren-mode`, toggle it on and use the “State” button to make it permanent.